# going back to past case in switch

Tags: java, text, switch-statement

I am currently making a H.P. lovecraft inspired Text game. I am having problems with returning to a past case in my switch "loop".
The problem is that I have a combat, run and clue "check" and after the check I would like to go back to the past case.

CODE:

```
public void fightCheck() {
        lastPosition = position;
        position = "fightCheck";

        int a = rand.nextInt(101);
        if (playerAccuracy >= a) {
            attackSucces();
        }else {
            attackFail();
        }
public void attackFail() {
        position = "attackFail";
        firstTextArea.setText("Your shots misses, the enemy at hand \n"
                + "seems invulnerable no matter what. \nYou begin to doubt your actions and your will decreases.\n"
                + "The enemy counter attacks and you feel nothing but pain.\n"
                + "(You recive 2 damage!) (You lose 1 sanity!)");
        choice1.setText(">");
        choice2.setText("");
        choice3.setText("");
        choice4.setText("");
        playerSanity = playerSanity -1;
        sanityLabelNbr.setText(""+ playerSanity);
        playerHP = playerHP -2;
        hpLabelNbr.setText(""+ playerHP);
        position = lastPosition;
    }
    public void attackSucces() {
        position = "attackSucces";
        firstTextArea.setText("The enemy falls to the ground due to your attack to your suprise.\n"
                + "For a brief moment you feel at ease, but the thought of whats at hand brings you back\n"
                + "to your reality.");
        choice1.setText(">");
        choice2.setText("");
        choice3.setText("");
        choice4.setText("");

switch(position) {
case "attackFail":
                switch(yourChoice) {
                case"c1":returnToLastPosition();break;
                }
                break;
            case "attackSucces":
                switch(yourChoice) {
                case"c1":break; //inte tillbaka till fight
                }
```

The Case I would like to return to is:

```
case "mansionMonster": 
    switch(yourChoice) {
        case "c1":
            fightCheck();
            break; 
        case "c2":
            runCheck();
            break;
        case "c3":
            break;
        case "c4":
            break;
    }
    break;
```

Comment: The Case I would like to return to is:                                                                     
               public void mansionMonster() {
  position = "mansionMonster";
  firstTextArea.setText("A strange fishlike humanoid charges att you.\nYou need to think fast, what do you do?");
  choice1.setText("Shoot it");
  choice2.setText("run away");
  choice3.setText("");
  choice4.setText("");

Comment: please don't add Code in the comments, add it to the question by editing it. It's unreadable if you add it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Back in time I started learning software development by implementing small games like that, which were inspired by board games, so I can feel in your shoes.

First of all, you definitely shouldn’t think of returning back to a previous case statement as of leaping back to that code branch. Such design would make program barely understandable, and is considered as antipattern.

In a simple case, specify all possible outcomes and resulting actions in your branches, as in the following pseudocode:

```
switch (action) {
    case (runaway) {
        runaway();
        break;
    }
    case (fight) {
        boolean hasWon = fight();
        if (!hasWon) {
            runaway();
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Such "if-then" architecture is going to become pretty cumbersome as your game is gonna be getting new phases, locations and rules. It's a broad subject and there’re many design patterns to handle this challenge. Try checking out [this article on state-driven design](http://www.ai-junkie.com/architecture/state_driven/tut_state1.html). For further learning, dive deeper into "game state management" and "state machine" topics.

Comment: Thank you verry much. I began this little project at the start of my programming course. I will re-do the designing of the game. Thanks again for the link and recomedation.